# smallIcon is round grey blob when using actual payload of remoteMessage.notification.body

Tags: kotlin

I'm seeing odd behavior with the smallIcon being a displayed as grey circle when I attempt to use the actual String received in the payload of the RemoteMessage.  When I hard code it the smallIcon displays properly.

Tried moving the order of things I'm setting in builder which didn't impact it.  Also tried to set the String vs. String? to the value in remoteMessage.notification.body

```
 private fun sendNotification(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage?) {
     if (remoteMessage?.notification != null) {
        // Setup Intent to Open Home
        val intent = Intent(this, Home::class.java)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)

        // Parse the remoteMessage
        val body : String? = remoteMessage.notification?.body
        var builder = Notification.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notify_icon_small_white)
                .setColor(Color.parseColor(bgColor))
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setContentTitle("strive.ai")
                .setContentText(body)

        with(getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager) {
            val notificationId = getNextNotificationId(applicationContext)
            notify(notificationId, builder.build())
            Log.d(TAG, "sendNotification($notificationId)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Strangely, if I use the manifest file I can get the transparent icon with the white logo to display.  Only problem with this is it doesn't accept a different color for display in the drawer.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by using the Manifest File settings instead of using code to affect the icon and color to use.

```
<!-- Set custom default icon. This is used when no icon is set for incoming notification messages. -->
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_ic_notification" />
<!-- Set color used with incoming notification messages. This is used when no color is set for the incoming notification message. -->
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
```